In what way does Monotone Convergence imply LPO?
I’m studying the constructive proof that Limited Principle of Omniscience is equivalent to the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. The last step in the original  Mandelkern’s proof is showing that the monotone convergence theorem implies LPO, which is claimed to be immediate. But it seems to me that in order to arrive at LPO, one has to represent reals with their binary expansions to plug in monotone convergence (of reals). But the claim that a real has a binary expansion is known to be equivalent to LLPO, which is invalid in constructive mathematics. Is there a way to prove this without using LLPO?

As far as I can see, the "LPO" condition in your given link is that "If ${a_n}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a nondecreasing sequence of binary numbers, then either $a_n=0$ for all $n$, or there is some $n$ for which $a_n=1$."  To me, that statement seems to prove itself.

@Michael notice the tag constructive-mathematics.

Aside: I don't think that part of the paper requires representing a real in a binary expansion. I think it is just observing that binary numbers are also real numbers, so the decision sequence is a nondecreasing sequence of real numbers. So (if bounded) we can "construct" the limit.

@Michael, but it's not obvious that any real can be represented by a binary sequence. And only then we can think of the decision sequence, no?

We do not need to represent any real by a binary sequence. We just need to observe that a binary sequence is also a real sequence.  That is, $0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $1 \in \mathbb{R}$. Since ${a_n}{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a bounded and nondecreasing sequence of real numbers, we know $\lim{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n$ exists and is a real number.

Given a boolean sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, let
$$a'_n = \cases{a_n\text{ if } \forall i < n. a_i = 0 \\ 0 \text{ otherwise}}$$
Then the series of partial sums $(\sum_{i = 0}^{n} a'_i)_n$ is monotone and bounded by 1, so it converges to $\ell$. We then have either $\ell < \frac{2}{3}$, in which case $\ell = 0$ and $a_n = 0$ for all $n$, or $\ell > \frac{1}{3}$, in which case $\ell = 1$ and there exists an $n$ for which $a_n = 1$.
EDIT: as Dan Doel points out, the "decision sequences" defined in the paper are already monotone and bounded, so one can skip the first step.

Right, didn't think of constructing a sequence based on the subintervals. Thanks

Note: in the linked paper, $a_n$ is already a monotone (nondecreasing) sequence of $0$s and $1$s, so it isn't even necessary to go through $a'$. This proof works for LPO on arbitrary sequences.
